# My dash web app on GAE works as expected locally on my Mac but when deployed the input box does not react to 1st entry attempt I type?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, plotly-dash

I think the short summary actually summaries the issue well enough. In terms of versioning , I am using python 3.4 locally, Debian Linux OS on GAE.Im running fin the production env. with 'cloud app deploy'.

I've tried to change the initial value of the input box , locally it is ''.the placeholder value of the input box ix'Start typing ...'.

I've researched online and tried to decipher the web page errors in the inspect element on my local browser.

There are also plenty of errors in the javascript on ''inspect element" in my local browser when trying this input action. One such error is "Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: component.type is undefined". You will see all of these errors if you try above in the web app address I give above. maybe another hint is that I am experiencing some other seemingly "unsolvable" issues. Such as the complete inability for me to host my static images no matter what I try from advice online (eg all combinations of app.yaml configs) . Maybe these two issues have a common high level source..??

My app.yaml config. file is :

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn app:app.server -b :$PORT

threadsafe: true

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
- url: /imgages
  static_dir: imgages

- url: /.*
  script: app.app

beta_settings:
 cloud_sql_instances: foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db
```

The head of mymain (outer) app.py file  looks like ,

```
# index page
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import sys

#sys.path.append('/Users/crowledj/Mindfule/dash-flask-login/views/')
#sys.path.append('/Users/crowledj/Mindfule/dash-flask-login/flask_login/')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__ , external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


#server=app.server

app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'})


from server import app, server
from flask_login import logout_user, current_user
import success, login, login_fd, logout
#import sqlalchemy

header = html.Div(
    className='header',
    children=html.Div(
        className='container-width',
        style={'height': '100%'},
        children=[
            html.Img(
                src='mindfule_company_logo.jpg',
                className='logo'
            ),
            html.Div(className='links', children=[
                html.Div(id='user-name', className='link'),
                html.Div(id='logout', className='link')
            ])
        ]
    )
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        header,
        html.Div([
            html.Div(
                html.Div(id='page-content', className='content'),
                className='content-container'
            ),
        ], className='container-width'),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    ]
)
```

And the head of the Source file which gives the 'login success' page layout and all running dash functionality is .., (note - the final block of code is the "input box" element in Q.)

```
import dash
#import dash_auth
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import plotly.graph_objs as go

from textwrap import dedent as d

from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from NutrientParser import parseNutrientStr_frmUser,parseResearch,parseFoodResearch,find_substring
from userMindfuleClasses import *
#import time
#import dash_table as dtable
#import base64
import PIL  
import urllib3
from PIL import Image
import json,os
import arrow


from server import app
from flask_login import current_user

#import dash_daq as daq
#import psycopg2
#from config import config


import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime


#db_user='test'
#db_pass='test1'
#db_name='foodnmood-db'
#INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME='foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db'


from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData,create_engine
meta = MetaData()

#engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:Pollgorm1@/cloudsql/foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db')
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:Pollgorm1@/?host=/cloudsql/foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db')


mealnMoodwithTimesnFoods = Table(
    'mealnMoodwithTimesnFoods', meta, 
    Column('time', String, primary_key = True),
    Column('id', String), 
    Column('food_1', String), 
    Column('food_2', String),
    Column('food_3', String), 
    Column('mood', String), 

)

meta.create_all(engine)


researchDict=pd.read_csv('./researchFindings2.csv')
food_perNutrient=pd.read_csv('./foods_perNutrientSheet - Sheet1.csv')

#prepare a .csv to use as the table
f_ptr= open("./nutrientRdas.csv","w")
f_ptr.write("Vitamin A,Vitamin B-6,Vitamin C,Vitamin D,Iron,Zinc,Magnesium,Vitamin B-12,Folic acid,Glucose,EPA\n")
f_ptr.close()

#user_1=User()

colors = {
    'logo_font' : '#797d7f',
    'logo_background' : ' #f2f3f4',
    'submit_button_font' : '#fbfcfc',
    'blue' : '#4530CA'                                              
}


layout = html.Div([

    #html.Img(className = 'company_logo',
        #src = '/.mindfule_company_logo.jpg',
        #style={
                #'height' : '8%',
                #'width' : '8%',
                #'padding-top' : 15,
                #'padding-bottom' : 20,
                #'padding-left' : 10
            #}),
    html.Div(children = [  
            dcc.Input(
                id = 'meal_input',
                placeholder = 'Start typing...',
                value='', 
                style={
                    'textAlign': 'left',
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                    'color' : colors['logo_font'],
                    'background-color' : colors['logo_background'],
                    'position' : 'absolute',
                    'top' : '100px' ,
                    'left' : '315px',
                    'width' : '300px',
                    'height' : '30px',

                })
        ]),
```

The expected result is for my attempted input text to appear and affect other components in the app just like it does locally. In actuality it just stays with it's initial text "Start typing..." and does not react at all. No error is reported.